# How to simplify FOR loops in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, simplify, sapply

```
for(i in 1:100)
{
  for(j in 1:100)
  {
       hdist <- rgeos::gDistance(xySpatialLines[[i]], xySpatialLines[[j]], byid=FALSE, hausdorff=TRUE)
       distances[i,j] <- dist 
  }
}
```

Is there any way to simplify j loop to get something like this:

```
for(i in 1:100)
{
  distances[i,j] <- lapply(???)  # or sapply?
}
```

UPDATE:

The data stored in `xySpatialLines[[i]]` - these are SpatialLines objects:

```
library(sp)
xySpatialLines <- vector(mode = "list", length = 2)
x1 <- c(1,4,5,3,2)
y1 <- c(2,5,3,6,7)
x2 <- c(4,4,6,3,2)
y2 <- c(8,5,2,6,1)
xy1 <- cbind(x1,y1)
xy2 <- cbind(x2,y2)
xy1.sp = sp::SpatialPoints(xy1)
xy2.sp = sp::SpatialPoints(xy2)
spl1 <- sp::SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(xy1.sp), ID="a")))
spl2 <- sp::SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(xy2.sp), ID="b")))
xySpatialLines[[1]] = spl1
xySpatialLines[[2]] = spl2
```

Comment: Have a look at `mapply` (multivariate `lapply`).  And you can always use a double `lapply()`

Comment: @Richard Scriven: My idea is to transform this double loop into foreach () %dopar% { #...mapply } O would you suggest to use double lapply? I am searching for the computationally efficient solution

Comment: @Richard Scriven: Please see the update

Answer (score 4):

You can use outer:

```
distances = outer(xySpatialLines, xySpatialLines, FUN = gDistance, byid=FALSE, hausdorff = TRUE)
```

Comment: Do you mean that this single line will substitute my whole double loop?

Comment: It should. I don't have sample data from your question to confirm

Comment: You can see what `outer` is doing if you try a few simple examples, like `outer(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), "+")` or `outer(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), function(x,y) x^2 - y)` or `outer(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), function(x,y) paste(x, "is less than", y))`.

Comment: @Señor O: I store SpatialLines objects in the vector xySpatialLines

Comment: @Señor O: It gives this error: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘is.projected’ for signature ‘"list"’

Comment: I provided the reproducible example

Comment: @KlausosKlausos if your input is a `list`, convert it with `unlist()` before feeding it to `outer`

Comment: @Carl and @Señor O I think the problem is that objects of class `SpatialLines` objects cannot be stored in a vector, hence its defaulting into list  even after `xySpatialLines` is unlisted.

Comment: @Ricky: What do you propose?

Comment: @Ricky -- **everything** can be de-classified, so to speak.  It may take a couple more steps, but of course it can be done.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft: I putted unlist(xySpatialLines) before outer. Still the same problem: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘is.projected’ for signature ‘"NULL"’

Comment: @Klausos unfortunately I have no solution; I ran into the same error and was trying to identify the cause of the problem, which as far as I can guess is that `outer` takes vector or array as input, and it seems your object cannot be unlisted to vector/array without losing other information in it (which may be needed by the `gDistance` function).